# VueJS + VueX Components render only on window changes

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vue.js, vuex

I'm using VueJS with VueX state manager, and for some reason the component only renders when i click on the component in devtools / when i resize the screen / open inspection tool.

I have implemented the same structure of code as in the examples.

Has anyone experienced that behavior ?

https://gifyu.com/images/20170227-133511_capture.gif

Comment: Might be some computed property that is not reactive?

Comment: @Borjante doesn't make sense, i'm using it the same as it is used in the VueX examples. :(